# Past simple or past perfect in this sentence

Tags: past-tense

I was going to finalise my order but when  I saw that paypal **had added** 20 euros for the postage to France, I did not, because 20 seems to me, too much.

Will it be better to use past simple for added and not past perfect, I think past perfect is better in this case because first paypal added the postage then I saw it and was badly surprised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Past perfect works well.

The narrative, up to "because" is in the past tense, but paypal added €20 before the time described in the narrative, so you can use past perfect.

Consider what the person would say if they were describing the actions as they happened "I'm going to finalise, but first I check the bill. Oh my! Paypal *has added* €20. That seems too much. I won't finalise this order."